# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface - LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, fatal-error, interface

I moved fully working Magento 2 to a different host (same server settings) and now I'm getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Configu...') 
 #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php(46): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Configu...') 
 #2 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice), Object(Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool), Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\Confi in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

I have no additional modules installed, nothing has been changed in any files.
Searched all over the internet, but all the previous cases are related to Magento 2 installation so no luck.

Any advice how to debug this would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try running magento commands like `di:compile`, `setup:upgrade` & `static:content:deploy`

Comment: Hi, yes tried all in both developer and production modes, still no luck. It seems that error is created from:

<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

Comment: can you paste the code of that file?